# Update IList data

Tags: c#, linq, ilist

I have used two `IList` object. In first list, it contains 10 records and the second contains 5 records. Now I want to `update the first IList with second IList data`.

```
foreach (ObjList newlist in New)
{
    ObjList list = ExtList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == newlist.Id);

    if (list!= null)
    {
        ExtList.Remove(list);
        ExtList.Add(newlist);
    }
}
```

I tried the above. But the added object appended at the end of the list. So sort order changed. I need it in the same existing order.

**Updated**

I tried the sorting, but it is not sorted.

```
ExtList.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: You're question isn't very clear. Can you give an example, and define what `same existing order` means ?

Comment: What's stopping you from sorting the list again?

Comment: This is actually sample code only...

Comment: `Sort` should be : `ExtList＝ExtList.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`IList.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add new item at the index of to-be-replaced item, so that you can keep the list in it's original order :

```
ObjList list = ExtList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == newlist.Id);

if (list!= null)
{
    var position = ExtList.IndexOf(list);
    ExtList.Insert(position, newlist);
    ExtList.Remove(list);
}
```

Comment: `Remove` should happen at last? or Can I do it before `Insert`?

Comment: @Jesuraja yes, you can.

Comment: `position` is always `0`. So all the extraced list inserted at `index 0`.

Comment: debug your code. see content of the list, does the item actually at index 0?

Comment: After debugging only I put those comments

Comment: That's sounds impossible. if it returns 0, means the item is at index 0. No way all items can be at index 0 at the same time.. Post *complete-but-concise* codes that replicate the problem, this worked fine in my test application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59560/discussion-between-jesuraja-and-har07).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the order after update, you can :

```
ExtList=(from e in ExtList
        join n in New
        on e.Id equals n.Id into left
        from n in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new /*Class Name */
        {
           Id=e.Id,
           Name=n==null?e.Name:n.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExtList.IndexOf` instead `ExtList.FirstOrDefault`.
And then use `ExtList.Insert` to given index instead `ExtList.Add`